OAuth2 Password Bearer in FastAPI, token undefined
i am new to FastAPI, trying to get the token from the requests based on oauth2_scheme, but the token is undefined,i am providing a snippet below:
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="api/token")

def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
"""
Get the current user from the JWT token.
"""
print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
print(token)

token_data = decode_access_token(token)
return {"username": token_data.username, "id": token_data.user_id}

i printed the token just to preview it but it print an undefined, what am i doing wrong why is the oauth2_scheme unable to correctly extract the token

If it actually prints undefined it usually means that you're doing something weird in the JavaScript portion that's calling the endpoint, as undefined is the default serializable value for any undefined variable. Try calling the API with curl or bruno - and use your brower's development tools to see what you're actually sending to the API if you're using in-browser JavaScript. It's also helpful to add the actual request you're sending to your question, so that people can see what you're actually sending.

@MatsLindh i am using the swagger docs built into fastAPi to test

I found a solution to the problem, I realized that FastAPI's SwaggerUI looks out for a particular keyword from the create_token endpoint which is 'access_token' instead of just 'token'. code snippet below:
@router.post("/token")
async def login_for_access_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    user = authenticate_user(form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise token_exception()
    token = create_access_token({"sub": user["username"], "id": user["id"]})
    return {"access_token": token}

